# Pre-commit hook

Tags: git, pylint

Всем добрый день. Нужно настроить прекоммит, что бы проверял pylint’ом код и если есть ошибки, то коммит не проходил. В ходе изучения этого вопроса понял , что в папке .git репозитория есть папка hooks и в ней есть файл pre commit.sample. Вопрос такой: какой код должен быть в этом файле, чтобы проверка pylint’ом была.
P.s. Работаю на windows